# reply message telegram bot

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I  know how to reply the message of users , but I don 't know how to reply the latest message made by the robot .

I need the robot MessageID

this message from user:
hi
this is a send message to user:

```
await BotAdminChannel.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, "hello user");
```

this is reply message from user:

```
await BotAdminChannel.SendTextMessageAsync(358434970, "How are you user", replyToMessageId:e.Message.MessageId);
```

but i want reply hello user
do i need bot_messageID?
how can get it

```
class Program
{
    private static ITelegramBotClient BotAdminChannel = new TelegramBotClient("token");
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BotAdminChannel.OnMessage += BotAdminChannel_OnMessage;
        Console.Title = BotAdminChannel.GetMeAsync().Result.FirstName;
        BotAdminChannel.StartReceiving();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private async static void BotAdminChannel_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        await BotAdminChannel.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, "hello user");
        await BotAdminChannel.SendTextMessageAsync(358434970, "How are you user", replyToMessageId:e.Message.MessageId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you shold use **reply_markup** property in [SendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#updating-messages) function and set it to [ForceReply](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forcereply).

read more about this in telegram bot api documentation:

- https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#updating-messages
- https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forcereply

Comment: Thank you, I've been looking for a similar solution for hours!

Answer (score 4):

Hi I hope your doing well, I'm a nooby myself, saw your question and worked a little bit on it and found a way obviously not a professional one but it somehow works
You see the `replyToMessageId:` works when followed by an integer and all messages on chats are numbered so you can find the number of the message you want to reply and put it afterwards `replyToMessageId:`
the code below will reply a message previous to the last message `Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id,"the text you want",replyToMessageId: e.Message.MessageId-1);`